# In CUDA profiler nvvp, what does the "Shared/Global Memory Replay Overhead" mean? How is it computed?

Tags: performance, cuda, overhead, gpu-shared-memory

When we use `CUDA` profiler `nvvp`, there are several "overhead"s correlated with instructions, for example:

- Branch Divergence Overhead;
- Shared/Global Memory Replay Overhead; and
- Local/Global Cache Replay Overhead.

My Questions are:

1. What cause(s) these overheads?
2. How are they computed?
3. Similarly, how are Global Load/Store Efficiency computed?

Attachment: I've found all the formulas computing these overheads in the 'CUDA Profiler Users Guide' packed in the CUDA 5 toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some of the answers to your question here:

[Why does CUDA Profiler indicate replayed instructions: 82% != global replay + local replay + shared replay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187489/why-does-cuda-profiler-indicate-replayed-instructions-82-global-replay-lo)

> **Replayed Instructions (%)** This gives the percentage of
>   instructions replayed during kernel execution. Replayed instructions
>   are the difference between the numbers of instructions that are
>   actually issued by the hardware to the number of instructions that are
>   to be executed by the kernel. Ideally this should be zero. This is
>   calculated as 100 * (instructions issued - instruction executed) /
>   instruction issued
>
> **Global memory replay (%)** Percentage of replayed instructions
>   caused due to global memory accesses. This is calculated as 100 * (l1
>   global load miss) / instructions issued
>
> **Local memory replay (%)** Percentage of replayed instructions caused
>   due to local memory accesses. This is calculated as 100 * (l1 local
>   load miss + l1 local store miss) / instructions issued
>
> **Shared bank conflict replay (%)** Percentage of replayed
>   instructions caused due to shared memory bank conflicts. This is
>   calculated as 100 * (l1 shared conflict)/ instructions issued

Comment: Thanks for your answers, BenC, I've figured out the "Replayed Instructions" and "Shared bank conflict replay" percentages. However, given the formulae for "Global/Local memory" replays, I still can't grasp why the global/local cache misses would cause instruction replays. When cache misses happen, it just needs to go to global memory to fetch what are needed, WHY REPLAY?

Comment: I think you can find some answers to your question in [these slides](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/bandwidthlimitedkernels_webinar.pdf). Memory operations are issued per warp, just like every other instruction. When a warp requests the next words, a poor memory coalescing will lead to multiple l1 load misses, thus causing instruction replays. Note that I am no CUDA expert so my understanding may not be correct :-)

Comment: This [other link](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/8266383.html) may be what you were looking for, but the technical details require some real motivation.

Comment: Thank you for these useful materials!