# Branch and predicated instructions

Tags: cuda, simd

[Section 5.4.2](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#control-flow-instructions) of the CUDA C Programming Guide states that branch divergence is handled either by "branch instructions" or, under certain conditions, "predicated instructions". I don't understand the difference between the two, and why one leads to better performance than the other.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223640/is-branch-divergence-really-so-bad#comment24956978_17223640) suggests that branch instructions lead to a greater number of executed instructions, stalling due to "branch address resolution and fetch", and overhead due to "the branch itself" and "book keeping for divergence", while predicated instructions incur only the "instruction execution latency to do the condition test and set the predicate". Why?

Comment: For an explanation about **Predication** in computer architecture, refer to [Predication (computer architecture) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(computer_architecture))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instruction predication means that an instruction is conditionally executed by a thread depending on a predicate. Threads for which the predicate is true execute the instruction, the rest do nothing.

For example:

```
var = 0;

// Not taken by all threads
if (condition) {
    var = 1;
} else {
    var = 2;
}

output = var;
```

Would result in (not actual compiler output):

```
       mov.s32 var, 0;       // Executed by all threads.
       setp pred, condition; // Executed by all threads, sets predicate.

@pred  mov.s32 var, 1;       // Executed only by threads where pred is true.
@!pred mov.s32 var, 2;       // Executed only by threads where pred is false.
       mov.s32 output, var;  // Executed by all threads.
```

All in all, that's 3 instructions for the `if`, no branching. Very efficient.

The equivalent code with branches would look like:

```
       mov.s32 var, 0;       // Executed by all threads.
       setp pred, condition; // Executed by all threads, sets predicate.

@!pred bra IF_FALSE;         // Conditional branches are predicated instructions.
IF_TRUE:                    // Label for clarity, not actually used.
       mov.s32 var, 1;
       bra IF_END;
IF_FALSE:
       mov.s32 var, 2;
IF_END:
       mov.s32 output, var;
```

Notice how much longer it is (5 instructions for the `if`). The conditional branch requires disabling part of the warp, executing the first path, then rolling back to the point where the warp diverged and executing the second path until both converge. It takes longer, requires extra bookkeeping, more code loading (particularly in the case where there are many instructions to execute) and hence more memory requests. All that make branching slower than simple predication.

And actually, in the case of this very simple conditional assignment, the compiler can do even better, with only 2 instructions for the `if`:

```
mov.s32 var, 0;       // Executed by all threads.
setp pred, condition; // Executed by all threads, sets predicate.
selp var, 1, 2, pred; // Sets var depending on predicate (true: 1, false: 2).
```

Comment: If I understand correctly: in both cases, the warp must execute both paths sequentially, but the branch divergence penalty is even higher with branch instructions due to the extra `bra` instructions? Could you elaborate on the book keeping aspect, don't all threads anyways have their own program counter? By the way, don't you mean `@!pred bra IF_FALSE; ` in the code with branches?

Comment: On SM 5.x and older devices all threads in a warp share the same program counter. The warp maintains a mask of the active lane (threads). Each thread has its own predicate and control code registers. The penalty for a branch is (a) latency to resolve the branch and (b) latency to fetch the next instruction. The compiler will use predication if it is cheaper than the above two costs. This is usually 6-10 instructions. If the branch is multi-way divergent there is higher cost as the branch (BRX) will have to be executed multiple times.